# find duplicate files in one folder and removing the newest one? (Google Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Properly a newbie question but how would I go about finding duplicate photos/gif's in one folder and removing the newest one?

The reasoning behind this is I have currently got IFTTT.com downloading photos from a subreddit and saving it to my Google drive, however for some reason it sometimes saves a photo twice but with the same name (no idea why but I reckon it's an issue with the reddit API). I have seen guides on how to find two duplicated files in two different folders but not from the same folder and I have no idea where to start.

So far I am using Rclone Dedupe to solve the issue however this only runs when my PC is on.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search research efforts a is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
function findEntry(arr, name, size) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i][0] === name && arr[i][1] === size) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function deleteDuplicates() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles(),
      list = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next(),
        name = file.getName(),
        size = file.getSize();
    if(name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".jpeg") || name.endsWith(".png") || name.endsWith(".gif")) {
      if(findEntry(list, name, size)) {
        file.setTrashed(true);
      } else {
        list.push([name, size]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked, I just added a folder by id before the var files = DriveApp.getFiles(), in order to only look at one folder